# IBM Worklight app-builder ant task creates two xcode projects instead of one

Tags: ios, xcode, ant, ibm-mobilefirst

my app-builder ant task is like that:

```
<target name="build.app" depends="eval.dev.params, prepare.app, install.plugin.pay">
    <exec executable="/usr/sbin/ipconfig" outputproperty="ip.addr" osfamily="mac">
        <arg value="getifaddr"/>
        <arg value="en0"/>
    </exec>
    <condition property="current.ip" value="${server.path}">
        <not>
            <equals arg1="${build.env}" arg2="dev"/>
        </not>
    </condition>
    <condition property="current.ip" value="http://${ip.addr}:${server.port}">
        <equals arg1="${build.env}" arg2="dev"/>
    </condition>
    <echo message="${current.ip}"/>

    <app-builder applicationFolder="${build.path}/${context.root}"
                 nativeProjectPrefix="${context.root}" outputFolder="${build.path}"
                 worklightserverhost="${worklight.server.host}"/>
</target>
```

The problem is that after this step I get two xcodeprojects instead of one and the ios build then fails and I don't know how to inspect "app-builder" work.

The two resulting xcode projects are named this way:

- /workspace/kWallet/build/myAppEnv/iphone/native/myAppMyAppIphone.xcodeproj
- /workspace/kWallet/build/myAppEnv/iphone/native/myAppEnvMyAppIphone.xcodeproj

Comment: The structure of the app-builder section is peculiar. Can you try with a fresh ant task following the Worklight user documentation for ant-builder, and if it properly works only then add the rest of the conditions? See user documentation here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/r_ant_tasks_buld_deploy_apps.html?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that they both are being build by ant???
The myAppMyAppIphone.xcodeproj, by looking at name format,  is the one built by the ant utility and the  other myAppEnvMyAppIphone.xcodeproj was built by eclipse.

When you use eclipse to build the ios env it uses the format

```
<project><app><env>.xcodeproj
```

where as ant uses the format

```
<app><app><env>.xcodeproj
```

Comment: Thank you for your obsvervations, I'm trying to figure out how to apply these to my situation beacause my project is entirely being built from the command line, but maybe some Eclipse command can get called in the process, but now this is not clear to me

Answer (score 0):

```
<app-builder applicationFolder="${build.path}/${context.root}"
                 nativeProjectPrefix="${context.root}" outputFolder="${build.path}"
                 worklightserverhost="${worklight.server.host}"/>
```

If you provide the `nativeProjectPrefix` to be the `projectname` then we get the xcode file name as same.